# nginx request that matches multiple server blocks

Tags: nginx

Suppose multiple nginx server blocks are matched for a request `https://www.example.com/bar`:

```
server {
  listen      443;
  server_name www.example.com;
  location    /foo { }
}

server {
  listen      443;
  server_name www.example.com;
  location    /bar { }
}
```

So `/bar` matches the first server block (even without `default_server`, as it's listed first). But it won't match a location.

Can I force it to somehow "fall through" to the next matching server block, which *does* have a matching location?

I read the [request processing](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) docs, but I don't understand what happens in this case.

Comment: Ony one server block proceed request.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: @AlexeyTen So it will choose first one, then fail?

Comment: Yes. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx select server block basing on `listen` and `server_name` directives. After choosing server block it will not change it.

There is an official documentation https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html, but I would recommend to read this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms